# How to move image with in the frame using gestures in iphone sdk

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, ios4, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

i'm new to use gestures, by using guesture i want to move image with in the frame..
can any one help in this..  you can find the image below.

[image]

Comment: what is the problem you are facing you haven't mentioned that...

Comment: Leena, actually i have a UIView, in side this view i have UIImageView(red color square in given reference image)... there is one option to select one image from the top.. here the selected image should be move this red color square only.. can you pls suggest the best approach  to achieve this.. Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/elc/iCodeBlogDemoPhotoBoard see this example.

Comment: Yes Leena, Thanks for sharing, but i have this sample with me... the requirement is i need to restrict the selected image to move with in the square only.. any suggestions pls...

Answer (score 3):

Hi VSN first of all cut the selected part from your imageview

using this code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tactile_noise.png"]];

    self.imageCropper = [[BJImageCropper alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gavandme.jpg"] andMaxSize:CGSizeMake(1024, 600)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.imageCropper];
    self.imageCropper.center = self.view.center;
    self.imageCropper.imageView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    self.imageCropper.imageView.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
    self.imageCropper.imageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8f;
    self.imageCropper.imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);

    [self.imageCropper addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"crop" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

    if (SHOW_PREVIEW) {
        self.preview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,self.imageCropper.crop.size.width * 0.1, self.imageCropper.crop.size.height * 0.1)];
        self.preview.image = [self.imageCropper getCroppedImage];
        self.preview.clipsToBounds = YES;
        self.preview.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
        self.preview.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
        [self.view addSubview:self.preview];
    }
}
```

check this example

https://github.com/barrettj/BJImageCropper/downloads

OR  **To crop the selected image part do like that**

```
// Create the image from a png file
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"prgBinary.jpg"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

// Get size of current image
CGSize size = [image size];

// Frame location in view to show original image
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
[[self view] addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];    

// Create rectangle that represents a cropped image  
// from the middle of the existing image
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(size.width / 4, size.height / 4 , 
    (size.width / 2), (size.height / 2));

// Create bitmap image from original image data,
// using rectangle to specify desired crop area
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], rect);
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 
CGImageRelease(imageRef);

// Create and show the new image from bitmap data
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, (size.width / 2), (size.height / 2))];
[[self view] addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
```

Refer this

http://mobiledevelopertips.com/graphics/how-to-crop-an-image.html

OR  To Resize the uiiamgeview do like that

```
- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image newSize:(CGSize)newSize 
{
    CGRect newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height));
    CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Set the quality level to use when rescaling
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, newSize.height);

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);  
    // Draw into the context; this scales the image
    CGContextDrawImage(context, newRect, imageRef);

    // Get the resized image from the context and a UIImage
    CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];

    CGImageRelease(newImageRef);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    

    return newImage;
}
```

**After crop or resize the your image to apply `UIPanGestureRecognizer`**

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
    [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [holderView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

-(void)move:(id)sender {

    [[[(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender view] layer] removeAllAnimations];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender view]];
    CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:self.view];

    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        firstX = [[sender view] center].x;
        firstY = [[sender view] center].y;
    }

    translatedPoint = CGPointMake(firstX+translatedPoint.x, firstY+translatedPoint.y);

    [[sender view] setCenter:translatedPoint];

    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        CGFloat finalX = translatedPoint.x + (.35*[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender velocityInView:self.view].x);
        CGFloat finalY = translatedPoint.y + (.35*[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender velocityInView:self.view].y);

        if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])) {

            if(finalX < 0) {

                finalX = 0;
            }

            else if(finalX > 768) {

                finalX = 768;
            }

            if(finalY < 0) {

                finalY = 0;
            }

            else if(finalY > 1024) {

                finalY = 1024;
            }
        }

        else {

            if(finalX < 0) {

                finalX = 0;
            }

            else if(finalX > 1024) {

                finalX = 768;
            }

            if(finalY < 0) {

                finalY = 0;
            }

            else if(finalY > 768) {

                finalY = 1024;
            }
        }

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:.35];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
        [[sender view] setCenter:CGPointMake(finalX, finalY)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**//NSURL CONNECTION WITH JSON PARSING:**

**https://www.dropbox.com/s/ubmaulkdhbdqha1/ViewController.m**

```
ViewController.h

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *tableView1;
    NSArray *practice_ArrayForDisplayingEx;

    NSMutableArray *arrRespone;
    NSMutableData *responseData;


    NSMutableDictionary *resultsDictionary;
    NSURLConnection *urlConnection;


}
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *responseData;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    arrRespone=[NSMutableArray new];

    self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.indiaglitz.com/json/vod_menu_init.asp"]];


    urlConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    [self.responseData appendData:data];

}



- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{

    [self.responseData setLength:0];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"didFailWithError");

   // NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]]);

}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");

    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[self.responseData length]);

    // convert to JSON

    NSError *myError = nil;

   resultsDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];


    NSDictionary  *arrDetails=[[resultsDictionary objectForKey:@"menu"] objectAtIndex:0] ;

    NSDictionary *genr=[[arrDetails valueForKey:@"categories"] objectAtIndex:0];


    NSLog(@"array detailsarray ====>%@",arrDetails);

    NSLog( @"genreee arrray==%@",genr);

    //NSLog(@"genrvalueeee -----%@",[genr valueForKey:@"genre"]);



    NSLog(@"counttttt===%d",[[genr valueForKey:@"genre" ] count]);

    NSLog(@"genre objectatindex==%@",[genr valueForKey:@"cliptype"]);


    for (int i=0;i<[[genr valueForKey:@"genre" ] count];i++)

    {

        NSDictionary *strDetails=[[genr valueForKey:@"genre"] objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *str=[strDetails valueForKey:@"gname"];
        NSLog(@"First string details===>%@",str);


        [arrRespone addObject:str];

        NSLog(@"response ====>%@",arrRespone);   
    }
    [tableView1 reloadData];
    }
#pragma mark Table view methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSLog(@"numberOfSectionsInTableView");
    return 1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 45;  
    NSLog(@"heightForRowAtIndexPath");

}
// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection");
   return  [arrRespone count];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"inside tableview");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";

    //TableCell *cell = (TableCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
   // cell.textLabel.text=[arrRespone objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"cellvalue:%@",cell.textLabel.text);
    NSLog(@"inside numberofRowsInsection");
    // Configure the cell...
      cell.textLabel.text = [arrRespone objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: please edit your answer and format the code to make it readable